# Communication between different subnets with different masks

Tags: networking, subnet

I was wondering if there is any way to communicate between two networks with different mask. For example:

**Network 1**: 192.168.0.0 / **29**

**Network 2**: 192.168.0.8 / **28** (which takes from the last possible position after Network 1)

This would be the network: http://i.cubeupload.com/zsCVlj.png

I can't seem to make this work and I wonder if this is either possible, or I'm messing something up.

Thanks!

Comment: It's going to be really hard to tell you what you have messed up if you tell us exactly nothing about it what you have done and what has (not) happened. And it is also not easily possible to tell you what you have to do as long as it is unclear how the routers are connected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that I tried to ping a computer from Network 1 to Network 2 and it failed. It was due to wrong configuration on the network 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network 2 would have to be 192.168.0.16/28 in this instance, which would leave an unused /29 between Network 1 and Network 2. You can't just start a subnet wherever you feel like it.

You should probably use something like this [online CIDR calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php) to double-check the validity of your subnets.

Comment: You were totally right... I was just starting to try different masks and I messed up with the Network 2's IP, now I changed it to 192.168.0.16/28 and I can ping computers from the other network successfully. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Or instead you should use

```
Network 1:  192.168.0.16/29 -- 192.168.0.17 - 192.168.0.22 useable 192.168.0.23 broadcast
Network 2:  192.168.0.0/28 -- 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.14 useable 192.168.0.15 broadcast
```

This will leave NO unused address space.

Comment: That's true as well! Thank you for your observation!